# Cast Map<String, dynamic> payload from Dart to Java HashMap

Tags: java, kotlin, dart, hashmap

How do I achieve this in Java?

**Dart code:**

```
Map<String, dynamic> payload = {
'id' : 2,
'name' : 'John', 
 'uniqueId' : 3733337,
 'books' : [
       {
          'id' : 3,
           'title' : 'reborn', 
       }, 
       {
        'id' : 4,
        'title' : 'trust', 
     } 
    ]
```

} ;

**Kotlin code (this works fine):**

```
 val payload: HashMap<String, Any> = intent.getSerializableExtra("payload") as HashMap<String, Any>
```

**Java code (this does not work):**

```
 HashMap<String, String> payload =  new HashMap<>(intent.getSerializableExtra("payload"));
```

Comment: Can you be sure that the value _is_ a HashMap?  There are many implementations of Map on the JVM.  — But the issue is probably that while Kotlin's `as` is indeed a cast (and so will throw an exception if the value is some other Map implementation), the Java code does not do a cast and instead creates a new HashMap.  And since you can't create a HashMap from any random object, you get an error.  Either match the Kotlin version by casting it (with `(HashMap<String, String>) `) without creating a new map, or (which is safer) cast it to `Map<String, String>` and create a new HashMap from that.

Comment: @gidds I've added the payload data structure.

Comment: Kotlin `HashMap<String, Any>` equivalent in Java is `HashMap<String, Object>`, not `HashMap<String, String>`. But anyway, to provide a precise answer, we need to know what is the type of the intent object, and what is the signature of the `getSerializableExtra` function.

Comment: @amanin Thanks. Understanding that Kotlin ```HashMap<String, Any>``` equivalent in Java is ```HashMap<String, Object>```, I updated my Java code like so : ```HashMap<String, Object> payload =  intent.getSerializableExtra("payload");``` and it worked fine. Thank you